# =TEXT([Date Column],"MMMM") issue

Tags: 2007, calculated-column

I'm using the calculated column formula below:

```
=TEXT([Date Column],"MMMM")
```

This translates my date in the date column (ie. 01/01/2017) into "January" in this calculated column.

However, if I leave my `[Date Column]` blank, then it will still display a Month in my calculated column (it specifically lists December)

How can I change this code, so that if my `[Date Column]` is blank, this calculated column will equal "N/A" or "0"?

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

You can use it as below:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Date Column]), "N/A", TEXT([Date Column],"MMMM"))
```

Answer (score 5):

Give a shot for

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Date Column]),"N/A",TEXT([Date Column],"MMMM"))
```